# Does the Always Encrypted certificates get copied over in availability groups?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, always-encrypted

We have a column set up with Always Encrypted, and we are adding it to an AG.  We'd like for the encryption to keep working if/when we have to fail over to a secondary server.  Will the Availability Group copy over the certificates, or do we need to install them by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [AlwaysEncrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), the keys are not stored on the server to begin with.